# Is there a way of getting a list without the nth item using a slice?

Tags: python, list

If I have the list `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` I can return the last four items using `list[1:]`.

Is there a similar way of doing this that would return the list without the second item?
I.e. `list[??] == [0, 2, 3, 4 ,5]`

(If there are different methods for Python 2.x and Python 3.x please detail both)

Comment: `l[:n] + l[n + 1:]`

Comment: @coldspeed Yeah, I thought of two slices but I was wondering if there was a shorter way

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey check linked question

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, just out of curiosity, are they duplicates? The other question is about removing elements from list based on value, not position

Comment: @djk47463 Questions like this I can guarantee they have been asked before, because they're good questions. Anyway, I found another duplicate I added.

Answer (score 1):

You can add two slices of the list

```
newLs = ls[:1] + ls[2:]

[0, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

You can also delete the element

```
del ls[1]
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought of two slices but I was wondering if there was a shorter way

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
n = 1

l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

new_l = [a for i, a in enumerate(l) if i != n]
print(new_l)
```

Output:

```
[0, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: That's a little long winded, [l[0], *l[2:]] is quicker

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey Yes; however, this is the generic case. [l[0], *l[2:]] will only work if `n = 1`